# OpenGL reshape and fonts problems

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, minesweeper

I'm developing a minesweeper game. I'm having two issues one with reshaping and other with drawing numbers. I'm using Ubuntu Linux. Following are the code snippets and the entire code is [here](http://pastebin.com/heWQLj27):

This is my initializing code that I write at the starting of main()

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition (400, 300);
glutCreateWindow ("MineSweeper");
glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
```

This is my display() func that I pass into glutDisplayFunc() which actually draws the grid requires for minesweeper game.

```
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glColor3f (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glLineWidth (3);

float i;
for(i = step; i< 1; i+=step) {
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(i,0,0);
        glVertex3f(i,1.0,0);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(0,i,0);
        glVertex3f(1.0,i,0);
    glEnd();
}

glFlush ();
```

I searched many forum and finally tried this code for reshape() function in the glutReshapeFunc()

```
void reshape (int width, int height) {
   glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1.0, 1.0);
   glFlush();
}
```

But it didn't work and the output was a plane window.

Also I want to display numbers in a font style almost as shown below in different colors:
[image: Numbers]

I've seen the bitmap fonts but they don't suffice my needs. Also is it better to use fonts or to draw them by hand using OpenGL functions or to import and draw images in OpenGL and if yes how do I import images such that they don't get distorted on resizing of window. I donot want the exact fonts as in the image but something similar would do.

Comment: " I'm having two issues one with reshaping and other with drawing numbers" What issues? You forgot to tell.

Comment: For better fonts use either FTGL (available on sourceforge), or learn how to use [freetype2](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/), or generate texture for fonts using [bitmap font generator](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/) and use them instead.

Comment: @SigTerm reshaping clears the display to the one obtained using display() function and I'm new and hence just don't know how to use fonts especially one specified in special libraries like FTGL etc. It would be nice if you can demonstrate using some small example